# APACHE POI 4.1 : Set cell background color from hex code

Tags: java, spring, colors, apache-poi, apache-poi-4

I've tried different solutions posted on stack overflow to apply a background color to an Apache POI generated cell, but nothing worked.

I'm doing something like:

```
Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(sheetName);

XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = ((XSSFCellStyle) workbook.createCellStyle());

if (styleObject.getBgColor() != null) {
    java.awt.Color javaBdgColor = java.awt.Color.decode(voceStyle.getBgColor()); // this is #FFF000
    XSSFColor bgColor = new XSSFColor(javaBdgColor, new DefaultIndexedColorMap());
    cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(bgColor.getIndex());
    cellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
}

Row newRow = Rowsheet.createRow(0);
Cell newCell = newRow.createCell(0);
newCell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

// write file
String pathFileExport = buildPathExportFile("test-export");
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(pathFileExport);
workbook.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();

//close workbook
workbook.close();

return Paths.get(pathFileExport);
```

I think everything is ok in my code but every cell styled like that will result in a black background.
[image: black-cells]

I have some doubts about "DefaultIndexedColorMap" instance that's during debugging results without fields:

[image: code debugger]

At this point, I'm not sure about what to do to solve.
Everyone in other posts seems to get things working but I'm still getting dark backgrounds instead of yellow.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As the other answer tells, usage of [setFillForegroundColor(XSSFColor color)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCellStyle.html#setFillForegroundColor-org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor-) instead of using indexed colors is necessary in `XSSFCellStyle` when it comes to customized colors. But usage of indexed colors from [org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/IndexedColors.html) is possible in `XSSF` too. And this will be the most compatible way if using customized colors is not necessary.

But also creating the `XSSFColor` from `java.awt.Color` should be avoided. The constructor [XSSFColor(java.awt.Color clr, IndexedColorMap map)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFColor.html#XSSFColor-java.awt.Color-org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.IndexedColorMap-) is marked "TEST ONLY". And `java.awt.Color` will not be available in some circumstances.

So if the need is "set cell background color from hex code" and the hex code is in a `String`, then `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex` can be used to get an `byte[]` array from that `String`. `Apache commons codec` is one of `apache poi`'s  dependencies already. Then constructor  [XSSFColor(byte[] rgb, IndexedColorMap colorMap)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFColor.html#XSSFColor-byte:A-org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.IndexedColorMap-) can be used. `IndexedColorMap` has no usage until now. So it can be set `null`. If `IndexedColorMap` gets any usage later, then the code has to be adjusted anyway.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;

class CreateXSSFColor {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx") ) {

   String rgbS = "FFF000";
   byte[] rgbB = Hex.decodeHex(rgbS); // get byte array from hex string
   XSSFColor color = new XSSFColor(rgbB, null); //IndexedColorMap has no usage until now. So it can be set null.

   XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = (XSSFCellStyle) workbook.createCellStyle();
   cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(color);
   cellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(); 
   Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
   Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
   cell.setCellValue("yellow");
   cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

   workbook.write(fileout);
  }

 }
}
```

Comment: Like rgettman solution, this worked perfectly even if I had to fix some lines of code.
I actually chosen this as solution because is more extrensive, talking about code maintainability.
Just note that I've removed "#" char from my hex code string "#FFF000" with a String.replace("#", "")

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed that when working with colors in xlsx files (XSSF), using indexed colors doesn't work very well.  It appears that there is no index for any colors in an `XSSFWorkbook` by default, so you can't use an index of color that isn't indexed.

However, you can use the [overload of `setFillForegroundColor` that directly takes an `XSSFColor`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.1/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCellStyle.html#setFillForegroundColor-org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor-).

```
cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(bgColor);
```

When I use this overload, then I get the yellow color as a background that you're expecting.

Generally when working with colors in XSSF you should use the `XSSFColor` itself and not its index.  This goes for other things like the other patterned color ("background"), border colors, and font colors.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks a lot.
Yes, using indexed colors is not very clear, even following api docs