# Apache POI 5.2.3 background color for HSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI 5.2.3 for creating HSSFWorkbook and I wish to set the background color of a cell. I have the HEX code color but I cannot find a system in order to use it. I know that I would use "the index of string code" like this:

```
getIndex(LIGHT_ORANGE)
```

but I cannot use the string like `LIGHT_ORANGE`, I must use string like `C0C0C0` and I cannot migrate on XSSWorkbook

Comment: Look up `LIGHT ORANGE` in the built-in colours list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `XSSF`the answer ist here: [APACHE POI 4.1 : Set cell background color from hex code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58594849/apache-poi-4-1-set-cell-background-color-from-hex-code/58603161#58603161).

That shows a solution for the first problem of how to get a `byte` array from a hex string.

But the binary Excel file system is very different in how to store colors. One cannot simply store a new color as `HSSFColor` as it would be possible for `XSSFColor`. Instead all colors needs to be in a color palette `HSSFPalette` and there are only limited free color slots. So to get a custom `HSSFColor` one either needs to find a similar color in palette or needs overwriting an existent color in palette. I would suggest to find a similar color in palette.

Following code shows how to do that:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;

class CreateHSSFColorOrXSSFColor {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (
       //Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("./Excel.xlsx") 
       Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("./Excel.xls") 
       
       ) {

   String rgbS = "C0C0C0";
   byte[] rgbB = Hex.decodeHex(rgbS); // get byte array from hex string
   
   CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();

   if (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
    XSSFColor color = new XSSFColor(rgbB, null);
    ((XSSFCellStyle)cellStyle).setFillForegroundColor(color);
   } else if (workbook instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {
    HSSFPalette palette = ((HSSFWorkbook)workbook).getCustomPalette();
    HSSFColor color = null;
    
    // either find similar color in palette
    color = palette.findSimilarColor(rgbB[0], rgbB[1], rgbB[2]);
    if (color == null) {
     color = palette.addColor(rgbB[0], rgbB[1], rgbB[2]);
    }
    
    // or ovwerwrite a indexed color in palette
    //palette.setColorAtIndex(IndexedColors.LIME.getIndex(), rgbB[0], rgbB[1], rgbB[2]);
    //color = palette.getColor(IndexedColors.LIME.getIndex());
    
    cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(color.getIndex());
   }

   cellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(); 
   Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
   Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
   cell.setCellValue("custom");
   cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

   workbook.write(fileout);
  }

 }
}
```

The code part

```
// or ovwerwrite a indexed color in palette
//palette.setColorAtIndex(IndexedColors.LIME.getIndex(), rgbB[0], rgbB[1], rgbB[2]);
//color = palette.getColor(IndexedColors.LIME.getIndex());
```

is commented out. If you uncomment, then the existent palette color LIME gets overwritten with the custom color. Of course the LIME color is then not more reachable.